# Python and Sublime: can't open file

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I have recently downloaded Sublime 3. It was working fine for few days, but today, while trying to do a project, it was giving me an error.

So I did the simple 'Hello world' printing and it still gave the error:

```
print("Hello World")
```

Error: [Sublime text 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV4xZ.png)

I also tried changing the [environmental variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOgLi.png) and tried to resintall Sublime, but it didn't worked.

Comment: Have you tried to store your project on another directory, different from Windows Program Files. It is not a directory for dealing with your projects. Give a try.
Besides that, make sure that the file indeed exists on its absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the picture, you haven't saved the pssa.py yet, that's why the error is `No such file or directory`